# WP serialized query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization

I have a simple problem but I'm locked for hours... I have a Wordpress database and want to update the usermeta table.

The value is a serialized value with the maybe_serialize() WP function.
My update query fails each time. I tried multiple thing to escape values, but it doesn't work.

Here is the final mysql query I want to generate (generated by PhpMyAdmin) :

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `meta_value` = 'a:2:{s:64:\"261d0952a424f1e8ef27ee77ef505c445c0aac5166f67e8d675bf06f717972d2\";a:4:{s:10:\"expiration\";i:1526328393;s:2:\"ip\";s:14:\"212.71.232.248\";s:2:\"ua\";s:117:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1 Safari/605.1.15\";s:5:\"login\";i:1525118793;}s:64:\"6f04a963506c545e0fb307135bd2eaf5178c8830c55048bb5d80cb7a8d730507\";a:4:{s:10:\"expiration\";i:1525556847;s:2:\"ip\";s:14:\"212.71.232.248\";s:2:\"ua\";s:121:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36\";s:5:\"login\";i:1525384047;}}' WHERE `mytable`.`umeta_id` = 48;
```

The original content of the meta_value is :

```
a:2:{s:64:"261d0952a424f1e8ef27ee77ef505c445c0aac5166f67e8d675bf06f717972d2";a:4:{s:10:"expiration";i:1526328393;s:2:"ip";s:14:"212.71.232.248";s:2:"ua";s:117:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1 Safari/605.1.15";s:5:"login";i:1525118793;}s:64:"6f04a963506c545e0fb307135bd2eaf5178c8830c55048bb5d80cb7a8d730507";a:4:{s:10:"expiration";i:1525556847;s:2:"ip";s:14:"212.71.232.248";s:2:"ua";s:121:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36";s:5:"login";i:1525384047;}}
```

How can I escape it in PHP to obtain the final desired query working with MySQL? I tried mysqli_real_escape_string() but it's not the same.

EDIT : Here is the result of the array after mysqli_real_escape_string()

```
$ a:2:{s:64:\"261d0952a424f1e8ef27ee77ef505c445c0aac5166f67e8d675bf06f717972d2\";a:4:{s:10:\"expiration\";i:1577790000;s:2:\"ip\";s:14:\"212.71.232.248\";s:2:\"ua\";s:117:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1 Safari/605.1.15\";s:5:\"login\";i:1525118793;}s:64:\"6f04a963506c545e0fb307135bd2eaf5178c8830c55048bb5d80cb7a8d730507\";a:4:{s:10:\"expiration\";i:1577790000;s:2:\"ip\";s:14:\"212.71.232.248\";s:2:\"ua\";s:121:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36\";s:5:\"login\";i:1525384047;}}
```

As you see, the escape is not the same that the one generated by PhpMYAdmin in the first query.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @Carrera, there is no need to convert array in serialize form while updating the usermeta value

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You say the "query fails". Please [edit] your question to give an error message or more details about what goes wrong.

Comment: Did the update fail even after passing the string through mysqli_real_escape_string() ? If yes, can you pls share the output of the mysqli_real_escape_string() and the exact error message?

Comment: @YogeshGarg I write direct queries with mysqli, I'm not using WP functions, except the maybe_serialize().

Comment: @O.Jones It's a classical "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax "

Comment: The interesting part of the error message comes right where you stopped quoting the error message: the part of the sql statement where MySQL encountered the error.

Comment: to use near ''a:2:{s:64:\"261d0952a424f1e8ef27ee77ef505c445c0aac5166f67e8d675bf06f717972d2\")' at line 1

Comment: I can't see any difference between the 2 escaped strings. The error message seems to indicate that you may not have enclosed the escaped value with single quotes to indicate that it is a string.